# Directory Service is unable to allocate a relative identifier

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

At work, we currently have one domain controller, POLLY. This DC is the RID master. However, there used to be two other DCs, PAULA and PETTY. These are both offline (and long gone), yet they appear in POLLYs configuration. Strangely, POLLY has the same IP as PETTY.

When I try to add a new user with *Active Directory Users and Computers*, I keep getting the following error message:

> Windows cannot create the object because the Directory Service was unable to allocate a relative identifier.

This is strange, since POLLY (our only DC) is the RID master.

Here's the output of `dcdiag`:

> Domain Controller Diagnosis
>
> Performing initial setup:
>     Done gathering initial info.
>
> Doing initial required tests
>
> Testing server: Standardname-des-ersten-Standorts\POLLY
>        Starting test: Connectivity
>           ......................... POLLY passed test Connectivity
>
> Doing primary tests
>
> Testing server: Standardname-des-ersten-Standorts\POLLY
>        Starting test: Replications
>           REPLICATION-RECEIVED LATENCY WARNING
>           POLLY:  Current time is 2012-01-11 09:18:28.
>              DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=europa-institut,DC=com
>                 Last replication recieved from PETTY at 2004-08-12 17:48:21.
>                 WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
>               DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=europa-institut,DC=com
>                  Last replication recieved from PETTY at 2004-08-13 10:50:52.
>                  WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
>               CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=europa-institut,DC=com
>                  Last replication recieved from PETTY at 2004-08-12 17:48:20.
>                  WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
>                  Last replication recieved from PAULA at 2004-08-25 01:05:28.
>                  WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
>               CN=Configuration,DC=europa-institut,DC=com
>                  Last replication recieved from PETTY at 2004-08-13 10:54:37.
>                  WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
>                  Last replication recieved from PAULA at 2004-08-25 01:05:19.
>                  WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
>               DC=europa-institut,DC=com
>                  Last replication recieved from PETTY at 2004-08-13 11:04:57.
>                  WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
>                  Last replication recieved from PAULA at 2004-08-25 01:09:36.
>                  WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
>            ......................... POLLY passed test Replications
>         Starting test: NCSecDesc
>            ......................... POLLY passed test NCSecDesc
>         Starting test: NetLogons
>            ......................... POLLY passed test NetLogons
>         Starting test: Advertising
>            ......................... POLLY passed test Advertising
>         Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
>            ......................... POLLY passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
>         Starting test: RidManager
>            ......................... POLLY passed test RidManager
>         Starting test: MachineAccount
>            ......................... POLLY passed test MachineAccount
>         Starting test: Services
>            ......................... POLLY passed test Services
>         Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
>            ......................... POLLY passed test ObjectsReplicated
>         Starting test: frssysvol
>            ......................... POLLY passed test frssysvol
>         Starting test: frsevent
>            There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the
>
> SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause
>           Group Policy problems.
>           ......................... POLLY failed test frsevent
>        Starting test: kccevent
>           ......................... POLLY passed test kccevent
>         Starting test: systemlog
>            An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x40000004
>               Time Generated: 01/11/2012   08:47:35
>               (Event String could not be retrieved)
>            An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x40000004
>               Time Generated: 01/11/2012   09:05:49
>               (Event String could not be retrieved)
>            ......................... POLLY failed test systemlog
>         Starting test: VerifyReferences
>            ......................... POLLY passed test VerifyReferences
>
> Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
>         Starting test: CrossRefValidation
>            ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation
>         Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
>            ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
>
> Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
>         Starting test: CrossRefValidation
>            ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation
>         Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
>            ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
>
> Running partition tests on : Schema
>         Starting test: CrossRefValidation
>            ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
>         Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
>            ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
>
> Running partition tests on : Configuration
>         Starting test: CrossRefValidation
>            ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
>         Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
>            ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
>
> Running partition tests on : europa-institut
>         Starting test: CrossRefValidation
>            ......................... europa-institut passed test CrossRefValidation
>         Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
>            ......................... europa-institut passed test CheckSDRefDom
>
> Running enterprise tests on : europa-institut.com
>         Starting test: Intersite
>            ......................... europa-institut.com passed test Intersite
>         Starting test: FsmoCheck
>            ......................... europa-institut.com passed test FsmoCheck

And here's the output of `repadmin /showrepl`:

> repadmin running command /showrepl against server localhost
>
> Standardname-des-ersten-Standorts\POLLY
>
> DC Options: IS_GC
>
> Site Options: (none)
>
> DC object GUID: 3c57a0b6-7047-4b42-a3d1-e5eed7513cbe
>
> DC invocationID: 5194142b-3179-4cff-b17e-77af398b8007

**What do I have to do in order to be able to add new users?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make a system state data backup on your DC, just in case.
Next, perform metadata cleanup to remove all traces of long gone DCs. Here is pretty good tutorial: http://www.petri.co.il/delete_failed_dcs_from_ad.htm
After that, run dcdiag again and let us know if problem persists.

Comment: That fixed my problem; I can now add new users. Thanks!